# Group algebra of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, modules

I already asked this question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447875/group-algebra-of-a-subgroup), but it was suggested that I ask it here. Below follows my question.

I think what I want to do is not very hard, but I am just not seeing it.

Let $K$ be a subgroup of a finite group $H$, and let $A$ be a commutative ring with $1$.
Consider the group algebras $A[K]\subset A[H]$.
I want to show that $A[H]$ is free as a module over $A[K]$.

**My proof so far**

I think that the quotient $A[H]/A[K]$ is finite (if this is true, how can I show this?).
Then we can take the coset representatives $x_1,\dots, x_n\in A[H]$, where $n$ is the cardinality of the quotient.
I think that the $x_i$ form a basis for $A[H]$ over $A[K]$ (again, how can I see this?).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $A[H]/A[K]$ is not finite but $H/K$ is.

Comment: The proof you are looking for  is the same as [in the multiplicative formula for field extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#Proof_of_the_multiplicativity_formula_in_the_finite_case).

Comment: Note that $K$ is not necessarily normal, so $H/K$ is not a quotient group. Do you have an argument as to why $A[H]/A[K]$ is not necessarily finite?

Comment: The quotient *set* [$H/K$ is finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup).  $A[\Bbb Z^2]/A[\Bbb Z]\cong A[\Bbb Z]$ is infinite.

Comment: Regarding your example: $H$ and $K$ are finite groups, but the ones you are taking are not.

Comment: My bad, but this can be repaired easily. Just replace $\Bbb Z\subset\Bbb Z^2$ with any  
 *finite* $K\subset H.$ The point is that $A[H]/A[K]$ will be a free $A$-module over the non-empty set $H/K$ hence it is infinite as soon as $A$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $h_1,\dots,h_n$ be representatives of the right cosets: $H=\sqcup_i Kh_i.$
Check that the map
$$(A[K])^n\to A[H],\quad(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto\sum_ix_ih_i$$
is an isomorphism of (left) $A[K]$-modules.

Comment: Great, many thanks!